# Package is not working angular 2

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I am new to angular2 and I have problem with angular 2 package. I have been trying to fix the problem and I couldn't. I am doing some assignment/project and the teacher provide with `package.json` with assignment. I install npm in locally on project folder as well as globally, but I couldn't start local server. I am running the program at window. The problem is here, when I run npm start or npm start -server I got the following error:

```
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.12.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-boilerplate@1.0.0 start: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-boilerplate@1.0.0 start script 'gulp'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular2-boilerplate package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     gulp
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-boilerplate
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

`package.json` file is

```
{
  "name": "angular2-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "watch": "gulp watch",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install" 
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "browser-sync": "^2.10.1",
    "del": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-concat-css": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-inline-ng2-template": "^1.1.2",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
    "stream-series": "^0.1.1",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3",
    "typings":"^0.6.8",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.15"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you run an `npm install`?

Comment: @echonax , yes i did install npm

Comment: I'm not asking whether you installed npm or not, I'm asking if you've ran the `npm install` command in the command prompt where your package.json is.

Comment: @echonax, yes i did install npm in project dir

Comment: Do you have a node_modules folder inside your project dir?

Comment: @echnax, i got this warning with intsllation in project dir npm WARN package.json angular2-boilerplate@1.0.0 No repository field.

Comment: yes i have node_modules

Comment: Do you have Gulpfile.js?

Comment: @Milad yes i do have Gulpfile.babel.js

Comment: Do you have gulp-cli package installed globally (`npm install -g gulp-cli`)? What's the output of `npm install`?

Comment: @Jari Jokinnen this is error when i start npm start;  npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "\\\\storage.slu.se\\student$\\username\\ApplicationData\\npm\\node_modues\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start", gulp is existed in npm dir, but the path might be the problem